Where to find conlangers on the Fediverse?
I am interested in finding conlangers or even speech communities of some conlangs on the fediverse (most prominently represented by Mastodon). What are good accounts to follow?
Just now (i.e., in the month of December 2024) there is Jamin @bpnjohnson@wandering.shop posting one word a day from Valthungian, a Germanic altlang, with etymology. The word for Kiwi fruit is literally "rabbit egg".
EDIT: Another account to follow: Valannō Lyore @ValannoLyore@mastodon.world – presents not only own creations but also generously boosts other conlangers!
